# Find the formula of general term.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$0, 1, 5, 19, 65, 211, \cdots$

are the first few elements of an infinite sequence of numbers that satisfies the following recurrence relation:

$x_n = 5x_{n−1} − 6x_{n−2},$

where $x_0 = 0, x_1 = 1, x_2 = 5, x_3 = 19,$ and so on.

This means that every element of the sequence is equal to $5$ times the previous element minus 6 times the element before that. So, $5 = 5 · 1 − 6 · 0, 19 = 5 · 5 − 6 · 1$, etc. Using this recurrence relation over and over, we can generate as many of the elements of this sequence as we wish. Of course, calculating the millionth element in this way would take quite a while.

Wouldn’t it be nice if, instead, we could find a formula for $x_n$, that is, express xn as some explicit function in the variable n? Using some linear algebra this is indeed possible. In the following your mission is to find a formula for xn.

(a) Find a $2 \times 2$ matrix $M =\{\{a, b\},\{ c d \}\}$
such that for all natural numbers $n \geq 2$

{{xn , xn−1}} = M^n-1 {{xn−1,xn−2}}

(b) Find the eigenvalues of M.

(c) Find the eigenvectors of M.

(d) Diagonalize M, i.e., write M in the form M = NDN^−1, where D is a diagonal matrix.

(e) From (a) we see for all natural number n ≥ 2 
{{xn , xn−1}}= M^n−1{{1,0}}. Derive a formula for xn from this and (d).

Comment: Hello. Could you be more specific with your enquiry? It seems like what you wrote in an entire sheet of questions. Which one interests you?

Answer (score 1):

Concerning $$x_n=5 x_{n-1}-6x_{n-2}$$ the characteristic equation is $$r^2=5r-6$$ the roots of which being $r=2$ and $r=3$. So, the general solution is $$x_n=c_1 2^n+c_2 3^n$$

Now, apply the conditions to get $c_1,c_2$.

Being very, very patient, you would find that the millionth element is "close" to $1.7977\times 10^{477121}$

Comment: Your sequence is valid of course. Why we have no other solutions?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg. For sure, I would like to learn about another solution. I use to be on this site in order to learn more and as much as I can. Cheers.

Comment: You need to prove it, otherwise your solution is not full. See please my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution. Dedicated to dear  Claude Leibovici.

We need to solve
$$x_n-2x_{n-1}=3\left(x_{n-1}-2x_{n-2}\right).$$
Now, let $a_{n}=x_n-2x_{n-1}$.

Thus, $a_{n}=3a_{n-1}$ and $a_1=1$, which is a geometric sequence.

Thus, $a_n=1\cdot3^{n-1}=3^{n-1}$, which gives
$$x_n-2x_{n-1}=3^{n-1}.$$

From here we obtain:
$$x_n-2x_{n-1}=3^{n-1}$$
$$2x_{n-1}-2^2x_{n-2}=2^1\cdot3^{n-2}$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$2^{n-1}x_1-2^nx_0=2^{n-1}\cdot3^{0}.$$

Now, after summing of these equalities we obtain:
$$x_n-2^nx_0=\left(1+\frac{2}{3}+...+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1}\right)3^{n-1}=\frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n-1}{\frac{2}{3}-1}\cdot3^{n-1}=3^n-2^n$$
and since $x_0=0$, we obtain $x_n=3^n-2^n$.

Easy to check that this sequence is valid and we are done!

Comment: Thank you for dedicating your answer to the old man ! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, rewrite as:
$$x_n-3x_{n-1}=2(x_{n-1}-3x_{n-2}).$$
Denote $a_n=x_n-3x_{n-1}$ to get:
$$a_n=2a_{n-1}, a_1=1 \Rightarrow a_n=2^{n-1}.$$
Hence the original $2$-order difference equation becomes the $1$-order:
$$x_n-x_{n-1}=2^{n-1}, x_0=1.$$
Dividing by $2^n$ and denoting $\frac{x_n}{2^n}$ it becomes:
$$b_n-\frac32b_{n-1}=\frac12, b_0=0.$$
It is again $1$-order equation, whose solution is:
$$b_n=\left(\frac32\right)^n-1.$$
Hence:
$$x_n=2^n\cdot b_n=3^n-2^n.$$
Appendix: To check validity, plug it into the original equation:
$$3^n-2^n=5(3^{n-1}-2^{n-1})-6(3^{n-2}-2^{n-2}) \Rightarrow$$
$$9\cdot 3^{n-2}-4\cdot 2^{n-2}=15\cdot 3^{n-2}-10\cdot 2^{n-2}-6\cdot 3^{n-2}+6\cdot 2^{n-2} \Rightarrow$$
$$0=0.$$

Comment: You need to show that your sequence is valid. Otherwise, your solution is not full.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The expression in (a) should have been $$\pmatrix{x_n\\x_{n-1}}=M\pmatrix{x_{n-1}\\x_{n-2}}.$$ To find $M$, write $$x_n=5x_{n-1}-6x_{n-2}\\x_{n-1}=1x_{n-1}+0x_{n-2}$$
Now you can find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $M$ and express $M$ in the form $NDN^{-1}$.